# Is there a major difference in the way we connect to FTPS server, using batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, ftp

I'm writing my first batch script to upload files to a FTPS server. I see lot of examples online, using FTP. Will there be a major difference in the way we connect to FTPS server?

Thanks,
dgk

Comment: That all depends on the FTPS server software.

Comment: Hello @vcsjones, could you tell me what is that I need to take into account to establish connection with the FTPS server?

Answer (score 0):

Both FTP and FTPSecure both use the same protocols, however, FTPS uses FTP with TLS or SSL.  Unless the client software is made to handle TLS or SSL, it will not work.  From what I know off hand, the built in windows `ftp` command does not support FTPS.  You will have to use a third party ftps client solution.